# Execute code when SecureField gets focused/unfocused in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, textfield, swiftui

I have a SecureField in SwiftUI. When this Field gets focused (when the user taps it) I want to manipulate a @State property for applying a offset modifier for the SecureField. When the SecureField gets out of focus the @State property should get reseted again. I want to do this for the SecureField to be visible if the keyboard gets toggled.

I achieved this with a TextField by using the onEditingChanged parameter of it, but this parameter doesn't exist for a SecureField.

How can I do this with a SecureField in SwiftUI?

This applies a offset if the TextField is focused:

```
import SwiftUI

let lightGreyColor = Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0)

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var textFieldString: String = ""

    @State private var editingMode: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SecureField($textFieldString, placeholder: Text("My placeholder"))
            }
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .padding()
            .offset(y: editingMode ? -150 : 0)
    }
}
```

But how to achieve the same with a SecureField in SwiftUI which doesn't have a onEditingChanged parameter?

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var textFieldString: String = ""

    @State private var editingMode: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SecureField($textFieldString, placeholder: Text("My placeholder"))
            }
            .padding()
            .background(lightGreyColor)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)
            .padding()
            .offset(y: editingMode ? -150 : 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no **onEditingChanged** for SecureField. But there is for TextField. Don't know why?

Comment: did we figure this out, i'm having the same issue

Comment: @Andreas why dont you observe the keyboard will show publisher?

Comment: Let me clarify something: focus and editing are two different things. There are two kinds of focus: hardware keyboard focus, and accessibility focus. Apple's definition of focus is that focus lets the user select what they want to activate before actually activating it. When Accessibility > Full Keyboard Access is ON, you can use the keyboard to focus a text field, before you start editing it. In fact you can focus on a different field than the one being edited.

Answer (score 1):

`SwiftUI` have no Method of  `focused/unfocused`. You need to achieve this using `@state` and `@observablle` and `onTapGesture`. But `onTapGesture` call Every time when `SecureField` is taped.

```
SecureField($textFieldString, placeholder: Text("My placeholder"))
            }
.onTapGesture {
//here apply condition

}
```

Comment: If the user is using a hardware keyboard, they can focus a field without editing it AND without tapping on it. So this answer is kind of wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue using the UITextField as before, and toggle its `secureTextEntry` field, instead of using the SecureField component.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am trying do this only with SwiftUI framework for learning what is possible